# Simple IBM DB2 Trigger

Tags: triggers, insert, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to create a trigger in DB2 (AS400) to insert/delete a row into a table when an insert/delete is triggered on a different table, but I need to use information about the triger table.

The example would be I would like is like this (column 1 from table 1 and table 2 are the same and unique in table 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON DB1.TABLE1
BEGIN
      IF INSERTING 
              THEN INSERT INTO DB1.TABLE2 (Col1, Col2) VALUES (Db1.TABLE1.Col1, 0);
      ELSEIF DELETING
              THEN DELETE FROM Db1.TABLE2 WHERE Col1=TABLE1.Col1;      
      END IF;
END
```

But this doesn't work (it doesn't recognize `TABLE1.Col1` on insert/delete statements).

Also it would prompt me an error (I guess) since it would create a duplicate key when a second row is inserted in Table 1. How could I avoid errors (just skip the insert) when the `Table2.Col1` already exists?

Comment: I saw some examples using both insert and delete on the same trigger, however that's the minor of my problem. I would like a working insert example checking duplicates. (I already reviewed that link prior to posting here btw).

Answer (score 4):

Try adding correlation names like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON DB1.TABLE1
REFERENCING OLD ROW AS OLD
            NEW ROW AS NEW
BEGIN
      IF INSERTING 
              THEN INSERT INTO DB1.TABLE2 (Col1, Col2) VALUES (NEW.Col1, 0);
      ELSEIF DELETING
              THEN DELETE FROM Db1.TABLE2 WHERE Col1=OLD.Col1;      
      END IF;
END
```

The trigger has access to both the old and new image of a row. You need to tell it which to use. BTW, only the update action populates both the old and new image. Insert only provides the new image, and  delete only provides the old image. One might think that SQL could figure that out, but no, you still have to tell it explicitly.

**EDIT** This is the final trigger actually used (from comments, thank you  @MarçalTorroella)

```
CREATE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER 
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON DB1.TABLE1 
  REFERENCING OLD ROW AS OLD 
              NEW ROW AS NEW 
  FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2ROW
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE rowcnt INTEGER; 
    IF INSERTING THEN
      SELECT COUNT(*) 
        INTO rowcnt 
        FROM DB1.TABL2 
        WHERE Col1 = NEW.Col1; 
      IF rowcnt = 0 THEN 
        INSERT INTO DB1.TABLE2 (Col1, Col2) 
          VALUES (NEW.Col1, 0); 
      END IF;
    ELSEIF DELETING THEN 
      DELETE FROM Db1.TABLE2 
        WHERE Col1=OLD.Col1; 
    END IF; 
  END
```

Comment: That worked. Had to add "FOR EACH ROW" or it didn't allow me to use "referencing". Now I need to catch (or avoid) the exception it produces when a second row with same ID is added to table 1 but I don't want to be inserted in table 2 (it's unique ID in table 2).

Comment: I think this should work but I'm having an error each time (even if no row exisits in Table2).
SQLCODE -407 SQLSTATE 23502
Null values not allowed in column or variable Table2.Col1.

The code I finally used is:

Comment: Sorry I don't see how to post code on a comment (there is no options)
CREATE TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER
    DECLARE rowcnt INTEGER;
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON DB1.TABLE1
    REFERENCING OLD ROW AS OLD
                NEW ROW AS NEW
    BEGIN
          IF INSERTING 
                  THEN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowcnt FROM DB1.TABL2 WHERE Col1 = NEW.Col1;
      IF rowcnt = 0  THEN
          INSERT INTO DB1.TABLE2 (Col1, Col2) VALUES (NEW.Col1, 0);
      END IF;  
          ELSEIF DELETING
                  THEN DELETE FROM Db1.TABLE2 WHERE Col1=OLD.Col1;      
          END IF;
    END

Comment: didn't expect REFERENCING to require separation by spaces when one wants to capture both new AND old, thanks!